# m is a macro defined as 10+2; why does m*m evaluate to 32?

Tags: c, macros

When I execute the following code on Linux, the output is 32. Why is that so?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define m 10+2

int main() {
  int i;
  i = m * m;
  printf("%d", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i=m*m` is actually calculating as

> 10+2*10+2

which is

> 10+20+2 = 32

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#define m 10+2
int main()
   {
     int i;
     i=(m)*(m);        \\this will provide you with output as (10+2)*(10+2)
     printf("%d",i);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I have another doubt in the following code regarding macro function.

Comment: Right error, wrong solution. ALWAYS put the parentheses in the macro definition so you don't have to think about it at the invocation.

Comment: Umm.. actually Aasmund has already given that solution so i went for an alternate solution to make it clear regarding the use of parenthesis for performing multiple operations in a single line.

Answer (score 5):

Macro expansion doesn't heed the surrounding syntax, so `i=m*m` gets expanded into `i=10+2*10+2`, rather than `i=(10+2)*(10+2)`. This why one should always parenthesize macro definitions and arguments:

```
#define m (10+2)
```